# In which entity the User Group details and user Group roles will save?

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

With reference to following link, https://asifaftab87.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/create-usergroup-programmatically-in-liferay/ I have created the user groups programatically. I wanted to know that in which table in the database the User Group details and User group Roles will get save? If I wish can it possible to add the custom fields for User Group using Expando API?

Any suggestions please.

Comment: If you're planning to write to the database: Stop, think again. You do *not* want this. Use the API to modify the data and never write to Liferay's database yourself. You'll break it, trust me. You might break it now but only realize that you did so in 6 months when you've long forgotten that you modified the database. Do! Not! Go! There!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users are stored in USER_ table:

```
select * from USER_;
```

Groups are stored in GROUP_ table:

```
select * from GROUP_;
```

Roles are stored in ROLE_ table:

```
select * from ROLE_;
```

Simple view of users and their groups:

```
select USER_.USERID, USER_.SCREENNAME, USER_.EMAILADDRESS, GROUP_.NAME 
from USER_, USERS_GROUPS, GROUP_ 
where USER_.USERID = USERS_GROUPS.USERID and USERS_GROUPS.GROUPID = GROUP_.GROUPID
order by USER_.SCREENNAME;
```

Simple view of users and their roles:

```
select USER_.USERID, USER_.SCREENNAME, USER_.EMAILADDRESS, ROLE_.NAME
from USER_, USERS_ROLES, ROLE_ 
where USER_.USERID = USERS_ROLES.USERID and USERS_ROLES.ROLEID = ROLE_.ROLEID
order by USER_.SCREENNAME;
```

Custom fields can be added for uses, groups and roles alike.

Comment: In which table am I able to see the user group name?

Comment: User groups are stored in USERGROUP table. USERS_USERGROUPS is the association table between users (USER_ table) and user groups (USERGROUP table).